# When polynomial GI implies polynomial (edge) colored GI?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, automorphisms, isomorphism-testing

(edge) colored graph isomorphism is GI which
preserves the colors (of edges if it is edge colored).

There are several reductions using transformations/gadgets
of (edge) colored GI to GI. For edge colored GI the simplest
is to replace colored edge by a GI preserving gadget encoding
the color (subdividing edge enough times is the simplest case).
For vertex colored GI, attach some gadget to a vertex.

Suppose GI is polynomial for some graph class $C$.

> Q1 For which $C$ polynomial GI implies polynomial
>   (edge) colored GI?

Using a reduction with gadgets might make the graphs
not members of $C$.

On the other hand certain gadgets/transformations
might make the graphs members of some other polynomial
GI class.

Example of edge colored reduction $ G \to G'$.

Make a clique of $V(G)$. Color edges in $E(G)$ with $1$
and non-edges with $0$.  It is the coloring function
that preserves $G$ and to recover $G$ from $G'$ just
take the edges colored $1$. $G'$ is clique, cograph,
permutation graph and almost sure in many other nice
classes. Subdividing the edges odd number of times
(distinct for $0,1$ removes the colors and makes $G'$
perfect bipartite graph, preserving isomorphism).

Maybe another approach is to take the line graph
of $G'$ and add pendant (universal) vertices connected
to vertices corresponding to $E(G')$.

> Q2 Are there nice gadgets/transformations for similar
>   constructions?

Thought about planarizing $G'$ by choosing some
universal drawing of the clique and replacing
edge crossing by planar gadgets preserving colors
say $C_4,C_6$ for equal colors and something else
for distinct colors. Don't know if this preserves
isomorphism.

Another possible approach might be automorphism
preserving coloring or subdivide every edge of
$K_n$, use 3 colors ${0,1,2}$ for vertices $V(G),E(G),E(\overline{G})$
and try to recognize self complementary graphs by
automorphism exchanging $E(G)$ and $E(\overline{G})$.

> Q3 Is the automorphism group of the subdivision of $K_n$
>   tractable to compute?

The orders after the few initial terms are $12 , 24 , 120 , 720 , 5040 , 40320 , 362880$
which is [A052565](https://oeis.org/A052565)

Dima suggests this might be easy for $n$ large enough and the initial
terms are exceptions.

> Q4 Given vertex colored subdivision of $K_n$ for $n > 4$ and its automorphism group
>   where the high degree vertices are colored $0$, some degree $2$
>   are $1$ and the other are $2$, what is the complexity to find
>   automorphism exchanging $1$ and $2$?

---

**Added** The paper [On Recognizing Cayley Graphs p 86](http://nozdr.ru.sci-hub.org/data/media/biblioteka/kolxo3/Cs_Computer_science/CsLn_Lecture%20notes/Algorithms%20-%20ESA%202000,%208%20conf.(LNCS1879,%20Springer,%202000)(ISBN%20354041004X)(462s).pdf#page=86) claims:

> Given a class C of Cayley graphs, and given an edge-colored
>   graph G of n vertices and m edges, we are interested in the problem of
>   checking whether there exists an isomorphism φ preserving the colors
>   such that G is isomorphic by φ to a graph in C colored by the elements
>   of its generating set. In this paper, we give an O(m log n)-time algorithm
>   to check whether G is color-isomorphic to a Cayley graph.

This appears close to the question, is it relevant?

Comment: How is A052565 relevant here? What are these numbers counting?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik The numbers are the orders of the automorphism groups of subdivision of K_n and they showed up in OEIS (modulo errors).

Comment: Do you mean a particular subdivision of $K_n$? (I have trouble reading English with missing articles). In your description, you seem to have defined a family of subdivisions for a given $n$, not just one particular.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I believe this is the usual meaning of subdivision: by subdivision I mean subdivide every edge once: (u,v) becomes (u,(u,v))((u,v),v).

Comment: OK; then please write "the subdivision", not just "subdivision". Anyhow, I am sure that the automorphism group of such a graph is easy to describe for any $n$. (not sure though what you mean by "tractable to compute" - by some particular algorithm? Or do you mean "describe"?)

Comment: The case $n=3$ is exceptional, as the resulting graph is hexagon, so you get 12. Then for all $n\geq 4$ you should just get $n!$.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik. Thanks. Edited with your suggestion and labeled the questions. Answers to other than Q3 will be of interest too.

Comment: Actually if you read details in A052565 you'll see that it is n! for n>3.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik by "tractable" I mean to find explicit generators of the automorphism group. (experiments with sage suggest they have relatively simple structure AFAICT).

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Indeed they write $n!$, but this is not _comments_, this is subsection of FORMULA.

Comment: the explicit generators are trivial to find. Indeed, the action on the degree 2 vertices is just the action of $S_n$ on pairs {[12],[13],..,[pq]...}, for p<q.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Thanks, I am not good at group theory. What about the other questions?

Comment: other questions are harder :)

Comment: @DimaPasechnik /me suspects so too. There might be a chance they are just polynomially harder -:)

Comment: Crossposted to cstheory:  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25936/when-polynomial-gi-implies-polynomial-edge-colored-gi

Comment: @DimaPasechnik related question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349706/complexity-of-computing-the-automorphism-group-of-the-subdivision-of-clique-with