# Complexity of computing the automorphism group of the subdivision of clique with leaves

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-groups

Related to graph isomorphism.

Consider the graph transformation $G$ to $G'$.
Make a clique of $V(G)$ and subdivide each edge once, i.e.
replace edge $(u,v)$ with path $(u,S_{uv},v)$.

For all edges $(u,v) \in E(G)$ add new vertex $T_{uv}$ and edge
$(T_{uv},S_{uv})$. The resulting graph is $G'$ and the transformation
preserves isomorphism.

What is the complexity of computing the automorphism group of $G'$?